# Maven profiles are not considered in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, profile

I have three profiles defined in my pom.xml:

```
   <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>ABC</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <url.base>http://server1.de</url.base>
            <url.searchevse>/search</url.searchevse>
            <url.reservation>/reservation</url.reservation>
            <url.cancelation>/reservation/cancel</url.cancelation>
            <xxx.devmode>false</xxx.devmode>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>XYZ</id>
        <properties>
            <url.base>http://server2.de</url.base>
            <url.searchevse>/cns/search</url.searchevse>
            <url.reservation>/cns/reservation</url.reservation>
            <url.cancelation>/cns/cancel_reservation</url.cancelation>
            <xxx.devmode>false</xxx.devmode>
        </properties>
    </profile> 
   <profile>
        <id>DEVELOPMENT</id>
        <properties>
            <url.base>http://localhost/noservices</url.base>
            <url.searchevse>/no/search</url.searchevse>
            <url.reservation>/no/reservation</url.reservation>
            <url.cancelation>/no/cancel_reservation</url.cancelation>
            <xxx.devmode>true</xxx.devmode>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In Eclipse I have a Run Configuration

> clean install XYZ

and I tried both using -PXYZ (and -P XYZ) in the *Goals* field as well as

> clean install

in the *Goals* field and XYZ in the *Profiles* field.

**The problem:**

The defined profile is never used.

Inserting the active profile under Properties-->Maven-->Active Maven Profiles doesn't work (or do I have to use a special syntax, e.g. no spaces after a comma or so).

Comment: "Active Maven Profiles" has always worked well for me. May the `help:active-profiles` goal be of use to you debugging this? You can run it from Eclipse.

Comment: It's weird that Eclipse is not able to fill the "Active Maven Profiles" field automatically by reading the pom.xml.

Comment: Why would it do that? If profiles are enabled by default (or by some smart activation rule), they will still be activated while in Eclipse. Other profiles are thus just meant to be manually activated, hence your option to fill that field.

Comment: It's always the last <profile> entry in the pom.xml that is used.

Comment: Do you have it activated in your `settings.xml`? What did `help:active-profiles` tell you?

Comment: I did nothing manually in my settings.xml (it doesn't even exist on my Mac). 
I should have been more precisely: I am using STS. I just imported the project into Eclipse and entered all possible profiles into "Active Maven Profiles". When creating a Run Configuration Eclipse was smart enough to suggest the profiles entered before. STS isn't. STS leaves the Profiles field empty and I have to fill it manually rather than deleting the undemanded profiles.
However, entering the profiles in "Active Maven Profiles" combined with filling the Profiles field in the Run Configuration seems to work now.

Answer (score 38):

Right click your project in the **Project Explorer** then go to

```
Properties --> Maven --> Active Maven Profiles
```

[image]

and type in **only** the profile name that you want to run.

If you want to run your `ABC` profile, type in `ABC` in the Active Maven Profile input box.

*The description(separated by commas) given there is a bit confusing.*

Once you define your profile name or id in the input box. You can **clean and run** your project on your server.

By doing so, your mentioned active maven profile will be run.

Comment: see screenshots at http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.gr/2011/11/how-to-activate-maven-profile-inside.html

Answer (score 1):

verify that plugin execution id are not equal in different profiles

Answer (score 1):

For those who still have problems. I am not really used to Eclipse nor STS but I actually use Spring Tool Suite Version: 4.7.1.RELEASE. I think the **Active Maven Profile input box.** may be named **Write here your already activated Maven Profile** :) as I think its purpose is to select an activated profile to run.

In my case, what I did was :

1. edit my Maven settings.xml (maven folder, conf folder) file to activate the desired profile with `<activeProfile>MyProfileId</activeProfile>` in the **activeProfiles section.** The one thing I really appreciate is that it accepts profile even defined in your project pom.xml and that is great for peoject with sub modules. If you have time, read this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
2. Then add your profile to Active Maven Profile input box (Ctrl+Alt+P or right click on your project, Maven, Select Maven profiles). You can also deactivate a profile with ! or - before a profile name.
   You might need to restart Eclipse.

The first step is only to activate your profile. So if you have any way to achieve this, feel free to do as so.

Comment: This really helped. Seems m2e plugin ignores <activeByDefault> elements in profiles, but respects explicit the <activeProfile> element.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse 4.20 you can right click on project -> Maven -> Select Maven Profiles...