# using POM to skip mvn integration tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, integration-testing

I have created Tests and IntegrationTests (IT) defined in the POM and classNames which I run from the commandline; I now wish them to run them from Eclipse. Here is the skeleton:

test:

```
package org.xmlcml.it;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue("simpleTest", true);
        System.out.println("RAN simpleTest");
    }
}
```

run with:

`mvn clean test`

and the integration tests:

```
package org.xmlcml.it;

import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class SimpleIT {

    @Test
    public void integrationTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue("integrationTest", true);
        System.out.println("RAN integrationTest");
    }
}
```

run with 

`mvn clean integration-test`

My POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
       <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>

       <!-- if this is uncommented the tests are all skipped
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        -->
        <!-- 
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        -->
    </properties>

    <groupId>org.contentmine</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple</name>
    <description>Test integration test</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

<!-- http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html -->    
    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run this from Eclipse (4.5.2) the IT tests are run. How can I alter the POM so they are skipped by default (and how can I switch them back on)? 
NOTE: I have used 
 http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html
for guidance but still have problems with the multiple ways of switching tests on and off (`@Test`, `*Test.java`, method `public void testFoo()`, `${skipTests}` ...) and some of the SO answers are labelled as obsolete. I am not clear which take precedence - is there an up-to-date cheat sheet?

Comment: You ask how to turn the tests on and off, but your pom indicates that you know if you uncomment those properties, you know the tests are not run by default.  Are you saying those lines are not working for you in eclipse, or is that a solved problem?

Comment: The lines are not working by default. Also I don't want to edit the POM if possible, because there is a danger that the full test  version gets distributed. Is there a simple switch in Eclipse?

Comment: I don't have 4.5.2 downloaded to test, but with 4.7.2 (Oxygen), you are able to add parameters to your build configuration.  I would use the full -Dmaven.test.skip=true (so parameter name should be maven.test.skip and value should just be true).  Sorry I know that may not be completely helpful, but without the same version, I cannot verify that would work for you.

Comment: You may also have some luck with setting a particular profile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140645/maven-profiles-are-not-considered-in-eclipse (while it mentions profiles not working, there is an example on how to set it properly).  That could give you the "easy" development vs production theme you are looking for.

Comment: I'll upgrade and let you know if it works.

Comment: Note that m2e does not invoke maven as such, but emulates the maven behavior.

Comment: You may want to move your integration tests to a separate maven module.  Then you can use the location where you invoke your build to determine what will be done.

Comment: Indeed. And that's what I may have to do. But that seems to ignore the maven apparatus for ITs. My impression so far is that there are ca 4/5 ways if doing it, they interact subtly and problematically.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running maven with `mvn clean install` when running from eclipse? If so, your're ITs are run because running up to install includes the integration-test/verify phase. To simply skip ITs only edit the launch configuration and  add a parameter `skipITs` with value `true`. That way only your unit-tests are run.