# Change default maven profile for Eclipse based on git branch

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I have a project which has different git branches and some of those branches must use a different maven profile. I want to make it so that the default profile used for Eclipse's maven build changes accordingly to the branch i'm in.

- I can't use activeByDefault in the pom.xml, sadly i'm not in power to make that change, i can't make any change to the pom actually
- I am already aware of Properties-->Maven-->Active Maven Profiles as suggested here: [Maven profiles are not considered in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140645/maven-profiles-are-not-considered-in-eclipse) but it doesn't seem to be some way to change it based on the branch
- I am already aware i could make different run configurations to be run manually but i'd like to rely on the eclipse's build workspace feature (i fear the day i forget to run the build when changing branches and spend the next hours trying to figure why my code is not working)

Comment: Let me be the bad to question the whole thing: Why should the build in Eclipse have a different profile than on a build server? If you do not change the pom, then you have profile that is activated only locally, and other people (your colleagues, Jenkins...) will not have this profile activated, so they get a different result.

Comment: Maven profiles have some strings that are written on spring application.yaml at build time (namely, the active spring profile) and our spring local profiles are different from server profiles because we use different services when testing the application from our own PCs (redis, activemq...). Everyone in the project uses those local profiles. There was an activebydefault until recently but now we have multiple local profiles based on branch and we have to rely on one of the non-automatic methods described in my question

Comment: Why are you writing the strings into `application.yaml` ...Why are you testing with different services ? Why not using a virtual machines or even better a docker containers to setup a local environment which is equivalent to the server one...apart from that I would never change the `application.yml` cause it contains the default profile which is used by default etc. To be honest sounds a little bit weird...and to be honest I strongly recommend not to use profiles cause this makes your local build different than the one running on Jenkins (CI) which makes it not easier...

Comment: While i agree to an extent to what both of you are saying, I joined the project one year and half after it started and i'm not in a position where i can make or change those decisions. I'm just looking for a way to make my life simpler where others made it more complicated