# Springboot ActiveProfile annotation is triggering test regardless of active profile being used

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured, spring-profiles

My Springboot REST API application uses RESTAssured integration tests with JUnit 5.  I would like to be able to isolate these RESTAssured test so they only run against in memory H2 database and to do so, I use profiles like:

- **application.profile** (which sets active profile to "development" or "production")
- **application-dev.profile** (development profile using in memory H2 database for testing)
- **application-prod.profile** (production profile using real database)

I am trying to isolate my RestAssured tests so that when I run maven > install, they will only run while I use "dev" profile.

If I use "production" profile, I would like not to run them as I dont want RestAssured tests to fire against real database.

I have my RestAssured test class annotated with `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` as:

```
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
class MyControllerRestAssuredTest { ... }
```

I would expect that if when my application.profile sets active profile like:

- `spring.profiles.active=dev`, maven > install would run `MyControlerRestAssuredTest`
- `spring.profiles.active=prod`, maven > install would **NOT** run `MyControlerRestAssuredTest`

However, regardless of how I set my active profile, maven > install will run the `MyControlerRestAssuredTest` tests.

What is that I am missing?

Comment: `@ActiveProfiles` sets the profiles that are active. As you're using JUnit 5 you probably want to use `@DisableIf` instead (`@IfProfileValue` is only supported with JUnit 4).

Comment: Hi and thank you.  I annotated my test with `@DisabledIf(expression = "#{environment['spring.profiles.active'] == 'prod'}")` and in my src/test/java/application-test.properties, I set `spring.profiles.active=prod` but the test still runs when I issue maven > install

Comment: Try setting `spring.profiles.active = dev` in your `application.properties`. Also check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19140645/3094731) answer for maven and Spring boot profiles integration.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
spring.profiles.active = dev
```

in `application-test.properties`

Comment: Thank you but that is another thing I tried but regardless whether I set `spring.profiles.active` to `dev` or `prod` in `application-test.properties` (which I added to `src/test/resources` folder, maven > install will still run that test

Comment: I also tried setting on my test `@IfProfileValue(name ="spring.profiles.active", value ="dev")` and that did not work either

Comment: Check your maven test profile, it is overriding the spring profile given in application-test.properties

Comment: Where is that?  I dont see anything relating to tests in my pom.xml